# CSS background image size scaling

Tags: html, css

I need help regarding background image size scaling.
code: http://codepen.io/AnilSimon123/pen/JRBRZa

here i have kept

```
  .bgimage{
  background:url('http://www.thedesignlove.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/free-blue-abstract-vector-background-6.jpg');
  background-size:100% auto;
  height:700px;
  width:100%;
  background-position:top center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}
```

As you can see the image has dimensions 588 x251 px.

I want the image to stretch along the width but keep its original height,all the while keeping the height of the container as 700px. The height of the image is dynamic.

Thanks and regards,
Anil Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.bgimage{
  background:url('http://www.thedesignlove.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/free-blue-abstract-vector-background-6.jpg') no-repeat top left;
 background-size:100% 251px;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimage">
  this is test
</div>
```

Use the `background-size: cover` instead  `background-size:100% auto;`

background-size: **cover** : 
Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

Comment: Using background-size:cover makes the height expand. I want the background size as the original height of the image ie, 251px.

Comment: I want width:100% and height: 251px. But since height is dynamic i cant keep a fixed height

Comment: But i have a requirement that i should keep height of the container as 700px fixed. The image coming as background from the DB should be stretched along its width all the while keeping its original height. I can get images from 1px to 700px.

Comment: Updated my answer. Now this should fix your issue

Comment: by giving a min-height:250px i am restricting the images i obtain from DB. If i get a 400px image it will only be displayed with a height of 250px.

Comment: I have removed the min-height property

Comment: but by keeping  "background-size:100% 251px;" are we not restircting the height property? If i get a background image of dimensions 400px ,it will appear as 251px only right?

Comment: i have a requirement to keep height as the original image height ...200 if 200 or 400 if 400 etc.. :(

Comment: For this you will have to position the image absolute to parent and use z-index. this it will have variable height.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `background-size: cover`

```
.bgimage{
  background:url('http://www.thedesignlove.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/free-blue-abstract-vector-background-6.jpg');
  min-height: 251px;
  width:100%;
  background-position:top center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Using background-size:cover makes the height expand. I want the background size as the original height of the image ie, 251px.

Comment: I want width:100% and height: 251px. But since height is dynamic i cant keep a fixed height

Comment: @AnilSimon replace height:700px with min-height: 251px; and add background-size: 100%; this will work.

Answer (score 1):

Background cover works just fine.

```
background-size: cover;
```

But don't forget to add also the background-position to fixed and center.
For more details you can check https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
    .bgimage{
   background:url('http://www.thedesignlove.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/free-blue-abstract-vector-background-6.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position:top center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    height:700px;
    width:100%;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left;
    background-size:100% auto;
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 

}
```

i think this is what you want

Comment: Using background-size:cover makes the height expand. I want the background size as the original height of the image ie, 251px.

Comment: I want width:100% and height: 251px. But since height is dynamic i cant keep a fixed height

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a container around your div with a height of 700px and add the bgimage on another div that is positioned absolute(so it doesn't affect anything else), height 251px and z-index:-1 to send it to the back. Also to stretch it set the background size to 100% 100%. Hope this helps

```css
.container{
  height:700px;
  width:100%; 
}

.bgimage{
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  background:url('http://www.thedesignlove.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/free-blue-abstract-vector-background-6.jpg');
  background-size:100% 100%;  height:251px;
  width:100%;  background-position:top center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bgimage"></div>
  this is test
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

.bgimage `{
background: url('http://www.thedesignlove.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/free-blue-abstract-vector-background-6.jpg') no-repeat center top;
width: 100%;
height: 700px;
background-size: 100% 251px;}`